# Find and delete all highlighted text in an email

Tags: vba, email, replace, outlook, find

I need to find and delete all highlighted text in an email body.

I tried to use WordEditor in Outlook VBA.

The following works in a Word document because I recorded the macro in Word:

```vb
.Find.ClearFormatting
.Find.Highlight = True
.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With .Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    MsgBox "running macro"
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

What are the necessary Outlook objects and code to include in the Outlook macro?

I know I need to dim ObjectInspector and a few other objects.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with the Word editor in Outlook you need to use the [Inspector.WordEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor) property which returns the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message. You can use the following ways to get an instance of the `Inspector` class:

- Use the `ActiveInspector` method to return the object representing the currently active inspector (if there is one).

```
Sub CloseItem()  
 Dim myinspector As Outlook.Inspector 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem  
 Set myinspector = Application.ActiveInspector  
 Set myItem = myinspector.CurrentItem  
 myItem.Close olSave  
End Sub
```

- Use the `GetInspector` property to return the `Inspector` object associated with an item.

```
Sub InsertBodyTextInWordEditor() 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector 
 'You must add a reference to the Microsoft Word Object Library 
 'before this sample will compile 
 Dim wdDoc As Word.Document 
 Dim wdRange As Word.Range 
 
 On Error Resume Next 
 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 myItem.Subject = "Testing..." 
 myItem.Display 
 'GetInspector property returns Inspector 
 Set myInspector = myItem.GetInspector 
 'Obtain the Word.Document for the Inspector 
 Set wdDoc = myInspector.WordEditor 
 If Not (wdDoc Is Nothing) Then 
 'Use the Range object to insert text 
 Set wdRange = wdDoc.Range(0, wdDoc.Characters.Count) 
 wdRange.InsertAfter ("Hello world!") 
 End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I think your second method is the right one for me.  I am in a n email composition window and the email body is fully filled in with text.  I need to use a macro to delete all the highlighted text in the body before I click the send button.  Can you help me to incorporate my code (which find and replace highlighted text with nothing) into your second method above?

Comment: You just need to replace the `wdRange.InsertAfter ("Hello world!") ` line with your code. prepare each line with `wdRange` object and re-use the `Find` object in the code.

Comment: Thank you.  I have changed my code to the following.  Please note that my email composition windows is opened and a full text is in the email body but the text has multiple lines that are highlighted scattered throughout the body.  I want the macro to do a replace all to replace all lines that are highlighted with nothing.  Basically to remove all lines that are highlighted.  The macro VBA references included Word 2016 library and so there is no compile error.  But when I run the macro, nothing happens.  The highlighted lines remain after the macro is run.

Comment: Make sure that you deal with a valid range object and it contains the required data.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try again.  I posted one with the code that I incorporated my code with your code and it did not work.  But my post was deleted by a moderator.

Comment: I have got it working!  It only requires minor changes to your suggested code.  Thank you very much!!!